# Why does the Tabbed Activity work well after I remove the code setSupportActionBar(toolbar) created by the Create New Project wizard?

Tags: android, kotlin

The following code is created by the Create New Project wizard of Android Studio 3.2.1 , it's a Tabbed Activity.

I'm so strange why Android Studio 3.2.1 want to add the code `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`, and why the App works well and can display 3 tabs after I delete `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`.

Could you tell me?

**Code**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mSectionsPagerAdapter: SectionsPagerAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)  //I can delete it


        mSectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        container.adapter = mSectionsPagerAdapter

        container.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs))
        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(container))

    }



    inner class SectionsPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {

        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3
        }
    }


    class PlaceholderFragment : Fragment() {


    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                                 tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:title="@string/app_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tab_text_1"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tab_text_2"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tab_text_3"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setSupportActionBar() method is used to designate the Toolbar as the ActionBar.

If you want to add backButton or add menu items, etc. in the Toolbar it should be designated as ActionBar.

Here you have not done any above things. So you were able to safely remove the line of code.

For details about Toolbar refer: [Toolbar | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar)